# Is $\sin \theta_{xy}\leq \sin \theta_{xz}+\sin\theta_{yz}$, where $\theta_{ab}$ is angle between unit vectors $a$ and $b$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces

Suppose $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are unit vectors.  The angle between unit vectors $a$ and $b$ is $\theta_{ab}=\arccos(a\cdot b)$ where $a\cdot b$ is the dot-product.

Is $\sin \theta_{xy}\leq \sin \theta_{xz}+\sin\theta_{yz}$?

It seems to me that it is, but I can't prove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily prove that
$$d:(x,y)\mapsto \arccos\left(\langle x,y\rangle\right)$$

is a metric. Then, 
$$\forall x,y,z; d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$$

Therefore, if $\theta_{xz}+\theta_{zy}\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\subset [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

$$\sin(\theta_{x,y})\underset{(*)}{\leq}\sin(\theta_{xz}+\theta_{yz})=\sin(\theta_{xz})\cos(\theta_{yz})+\sin(\theta_{yz})\cos(\theta_{xz})\leq\sin(\theta_{xz})+\sin(\theta_{yz}).$$

If you don't have the condition $\theta_{xz}+\theta_{zy}\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, there is no reason that your inequality is correct. Indeed, for exemple, if $\theta_{xz}=\theta_{yz}=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and so $\theta_{xy}=\pi$, then $\sin(\theta_{xy})=0$ and $\sin(\theta_{xz})+\sin(\theta_{yz})=-2$

---

$(*)$ because $x\mapsto \sin(x)$ is increasing on $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: I know the formula, but am stuck at what to do with it...

Comment: I changed my answer. I hope this one will helps you more :-)